# Spring authentication with Oracle JDBC10

Tags: java, spring, oracle, authentication

I'm following a Spring Course that the teacher makes an example of Spring Security (loging page with spring mvc) ... he's using mysql and i'm trying to do it but with Oracle Database 19c, width ojdbc10, but i'm missing something.

I have the same tables (user and password), with the same data in it, but when i try to log in, i failed in the authentication, like the user name or password is wrong.

Properties file

```
#
#JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.240.11:1521:orcl
jdbc.user=jcataldo
jdbc.password=Pola1095
```

App config .java

```
ort org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-oracle.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig { 
    
    // define a bean for ViewResolver ==> Indica que es lo que debería mostrar, en este caso todo los
    // .jsp ubicados en /WEB-INF/view
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env; //hold data read from properties file
    
    // set up a logger for diagnostics
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    // define a bean for ViewResolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    // define a bean for our security datasource
    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        
        // create a connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource
            = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        
        // set the jdbc driver class
        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
        
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // log the connection props
        // check if we are really reading data from properties file     
        logger.info(">>>>> jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info(">>>>> jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        // set database connection props
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        
        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        
        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        
        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        
        return securityDataSource;
    }
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }
    
}
```

I have NO CONNECTION ERRORS, but its like the data in the table user and password is not matching with my input in the mvc login page.

Hope someone can help me.

thanks in advance and sorry if i misslead something, i'm new in this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i messed up with the table's database, didn't follow the right schema, wich is:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
USERNAME NVARCHAR2(128) PRIMARY KEY,
PASSWORD NVARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
ENABLED CHAR(1) CHECK (ENABLED IN ('Y','N') ) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES (
USERNAME NVARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
AUTHORITY NVARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES ADD CONSTRAINT AUTHORITIES_UNIQUE UNIQUE (USERNAME, AUTHORITY);

ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES ADD CONSTRAINT AUTHORITIES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS (USERNAME) ENABLE;
```